# Django - File or Image Delete

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

The user has the possibility to add/delete image and documents.

I used GCBV UpdateView and a FormModel for this.

How can I offer the possibility to the user to delete the file/image ?

Comment: Post the relevant parts of your code. Use `django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to override the delete method of your model.

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    file_field = models.FileField(upload_to='folder')

    def delete(self):
        os.remove(settings.MEDIA_ROOT+'folder/'+self.file_field.path)
        return super(YourModel,self).delete()
```

This will delete the entry from the model and also delete the file from your system.

Comment: the proposed function delete the file when the model is removed(If I'm not wrong), I want the user to delete the file(of any reason) if he clicks a button or checkbox (there is similar functionality in admin for FileField, ImageField) , even if the model itself it is not deleted; I have the FileField as a separate model wich have a ForeignKey to the DefaulModel